# expressjs where to call next() in middleware

Tags: node.js, express

What is the difference on calling next() outside the end() function or inside?
Also does i need to call it into onError() ?

PS: I need the data in my next handler.

```
return function (req, res, next){

        req.setEncoding('utf8');
        req.rawBody = '';

        req.on('data', function (chunk) {
            req.rawBody += chunk;
        });

        req.on('aborted', onAborted);

        function onAborted() {
            logger.warn('Request has been aborted [IP= ' + req.ip + '].');
        }

        req.on('error', onError);

        function onError() {
            logger.warn('Unable to read request [IP= ' + req.ip + '].');
            // next() ?
        }

        req.on('end', onEnd);

        function onEnd() {
            next()
        }

        // next() ?
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that inside `onEnd` it's going to be executed asynchronously only when the `end` event is emitted. Outside `onEnd`, in the last line, it will not wait for the `end` event and will be executed as soon as the code reaches that line.

When developing an `express` app, it's a good pratice to pass the error, when it happens, to the `next()` function, and handle that with a middleware (like `errorHandler`) in the main file.

Comment: Ok i understand. In my case, i need to call it inside because my next middleware need the data.
If i get an error/abort, does end() will be called ? if not, i need to call next() with the error so ?

Comment: The `next` callback is optional, but since you pass it to your anonymous function, you have to guarantee that it'll be called once. And no, if an `error` event happens, the `end` event isn't going to be fired, because it only happens when all the data is consumed. So, in this case you have to call `next()` inside your `onError` function.

Comment: Thank you! When i detect an error, is it possible to directly send an http error code without passing in the next middlewares ? I suspect my errors requests to timeout.

Comment: Yes, you can. You can call `res.status(the_status_code).end()`.